# Dockerized Next.js app can't upload file to volume - Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dockerized next.js app and I get permission denied when I try to upload files.

The folder i'm trying to upload to is linked to a mounted volume.

```yaml
# compose.yaml

services:
  app-prod:
    build:
      context: .
    links:
      - app-database
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    env_file:
      - .env.production
      - .env
    volumes:
      - storage:/usr/src/app/public/uploads

  app-database:
    image: mongo:6
    volumes: 
     - database:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

volumes:
  database:
  storage:
```

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

ARG NODE_VERSION=16.17.0

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine as base

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

################################################################################
# Create a stage for installing production dependecies.
FROM base as deps

RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=yarn.lock,target=yarn.lock \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.yarn \
    yarn install --frozen-lockfile

################################################################################
# Create a stage for building the application.
FROM base as build

RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=yarn.lock,target=yarn.lock \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.yarn \
    yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile


COPY . .

RUN yarn build

################################################################################
# Create a new stage to run the application with minimal runtime dependencies
# where the necessary files are copied from the build stage.
FROM base as final


ENV NODE_ENV production

USER node

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build --chown=node:node /usr/src/app/public ./public
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/package.json ./

CMD yarn start
```

I tried adding `--chown=node:node`... public folder and subfolders ownerships changed to `node` but uploads folder ownership remained as `root`

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 node     node        4.0K Sep 14 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Sep 14 10:25 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 node     node        6.0K Jan 18  2023 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x    6 node     node        4.0K Apr 25 10:18 assets
drwxr-xr-x    2 node     node        4.0K Dec  6  2022 favicon
drwxr-xr-x    2 node     node        4.0K Aug  7 04:24 fonts
-rw-r--r--    1 node     node         441 Dec  6  2022 manifest.json
-rw-r--r--    1 node     node          67 Sep 20  2022 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Sep 14 08:43 uploads
```

---

this is the error I get when trying to upload:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'public/uploads/7f19ba13b767d8557a1262900.jpg'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:594:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2207:35)
    at saveFile (/usr/src/app/.next/server/chunks/4185.js:30:51)
    at /usr/src/app/.next/server/pages/api/app/meeting-room/[roomId]/edit.js:123:120
    at zalgoSafe (/usr/src/app/node_modules/dezalgo/dezalgo.js:20:10)
    at f (/usr/src/app/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/formidable/src/Formidable.js:183:9)
    at IncomingForm.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (/usr/src/app/node_modules/formidable/src/Formidable.js:612:10)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/formidable/src/Formidable.js:390:14 {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: 'public/uploads/7f19ba13b767d8557a1262900.jpg'
}
```

Comment: Usually ```chown``` should be used with ```--chown=node:node -R``` for recursive changes in ownership. Volumes for your prod and dev containers are different, please take a look carefully permission group used in both cases

Comment: Yeah you're right im not using `storage` volume on dev. I edited the question. I also added the ownership of all folders in the public folder. As you can see they all changed ownership except for uploads folder, which is linked to volume @Gleichmut

Comment: Please share link on your repository, I will take a look.

Comment: @Gleichmut I can't, its an organization's private repository.